# Use SSHFS with shared control socket

Tags: linux, ssh, sshfs

I start an SSH session with a shared control socket as follows:

```
ssh -M -S ssh_socket -fnNTC ssh://user@host:9022
```

I have no problem executing commands using this socket; for example:

```
ssh -S ssh_socket ssh://user@host:9022 -t htop
```

But I want to mount a file system over the same shared socket, and cannot figure out the syntax. This mounts the file system, but not using the shared socket, so it asks for a password again:

```
sshfs -p 9022 user@host:/path /path
```

Can anyone help me figure out if what I want is even possible?

Comment: This is one reason that `~/.ssh/config` is so useful.  In this example, adding `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` directives in your ssh config would also do the trick, avoiding the need to add command line options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

Use `-o ssh_command='ssh -S /full/path/to/ssh_socket'`. From [`man 1 sshfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sshfs/sshfs.1.en.html):

> `-o ssh_command=CMD`
> execute `CMD` instead of `ssh`.

```
sshfs placeholder:/remote/path /local/path -o ssh_command='ssh -S /full/path/to/ssh_socket'
```

Notes:

- In my Kubuntu the specified `ssh_command` runs in `/` regardless of the directory I run `sshfs` from. That's why this answer uses `/full/path/to/ssh_socket`, not just `ssh_socket`.
- If you use `ssh -S` without `-M`, some options won't matter. The socket will matter in the first place. It is associated to some master connection where the port, the username and the host are already fixed. Therefore there is no need to use `-p` and you can use almost any placeholder instead of `user@host`. Even your second `ssh` command could be `ssh -S ssh_socket -t whatever htop`.
- `ssh://user@host:9022` syntax you used doesn't work with `ssh` from OpenSSH in my Kubuntu. What works is `-p 9022 user@host`.

Comment: Thanks! It is working. Btw I had noticed the destination seemed to be redundant when adding a connection to an existing socket, but it can appear in error messages if the connection fails, and I wasn't sure if a placeholder was technically valid, so I superstitiously left it alone.

Comment: @Boann The actual destination is at least as good placeholder as any.